# How to react to action completion in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I want to have a popup come on the screen after an action completes successfuly in the redux store.

The first thing i tried was awaiting the dispatch and checking the error field

MyComponent.jsx

```
...
const error = useSelect(selectError())
const handleSubmit = async () => {
    await dispatch(myAction(...)))
    if(!error)
        setIsPopupOpen(true);
}
...
```

I realised this doesn't work because the error in the scope of the function was defined in the initial render of the component and will not reflect changes in the redux store. Which led to the following workaround.

MyComponent.jsx

```
...
const error = useSelect(selectError())
const [actionCompleted, setActionCompleted] = useState();
const handleSubmit = async () => {
    await dispatch(myAction(...)))
    setActionCompleted(true)
}

useEffect(() => {
   if(actionCompleted) {
       if(!error)
           setIsPopupOpen(true);
       setActionCompleted(false);
   }
}, [error, actionCompleted])
...
```

But this is definitly is more of a workaround, then an actual solution. I thought about adding the action result to the state of the store slice and came with the following approach.

StoreSlice.js

```
const initialState = {
   ...
   actionStatus: 'idle',
   ...
}
createSlice({
   ...
   myAction: (state, action) => {
       if (/* business logic */ ) {
           state.error = 'some error'
           state.actionStatus = 'failure'
       }
   },
   clearMyActionStatus: (state) => {
       state.actionStatus = 'idle'
   }
})
```

MyComponent.jsx

```
const error = useSelect(selectError())
const [actionCompleted, setActionCompleted] = useState();
const handleSubmit = () => {
    dispatch(myAction(...)))
}

useEffect(() => {
   if(actionStatus === 'success') {
      setIsPopupOpen(true)
      dispatch(clearActionStatus());
   }
}, [actionStatus])
```

But this seems wrong to me, adding an action to reset the action status after it is read seems clumsy and unlike usual use of actions in redux, but i might be wrong about this.

This issue seems baffling to me, because this seems like a faily common situation, but all solutions i came up with seems overly complex.

Is there a more simple way to handle this situation, if not which method is considered best?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to call `setIsPopupOpen(true)` for your Popup to work? Or can you maybe just track the Popup-open-state inside Redux? It depends your your Popup implementation but I'd go with something like this:

- have a boolean like 'popUpVisible' in Redux
- set it true if your action is handled
- select the `popUpVisible` in the Popup and use it to show/hide the component (keep it in the DOM but only change visibility, z-index - whatever is needed)
- if the Popup is closed, dispatch an action which changes `popUpVisble` to false